# how to set magento 2 parent categories setting yes/no from database

Tags: magento2

UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int set value = 0 where attribute_id = 70

**you can set parent categories setting yes 1 and no 0**
**attribute id you can find from database**

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'custom_use_parent_settings';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int set value = 0 where attribute_id = 70
```

**you can set parent categories setting yes 1 and no 0**
**attribute id you can find from database**

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'custom_use_parent_settings';
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'is_anchor';

Comment: UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int set value = 0 where attribute_id = 70

Comment: for anchor update